# Is Google identity sign in product HIPAA compliant?

Tags: google, hipaa

I want to use [this product](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/) to save me a month of coding. 
Looking for a product that

- Password expiration
- forgot password system
- lock after x times of wrong password
- Valid passwords rules (min 8 characters etc..)
- Edit users and permissions interface
- HIPAA compliance

I thought about Google sign in but I need it to be HIPAA compliant.
I've looked [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3407054?hl=en) but it states that only Gmail, Google Calendar, Google Drive Google Sites, and Google Apps Vault service are HIPAA compliant.

**edit**

Tried to find whether google fit is hipaa complaint because they use google sign in - they are not  :-( -> "Google does not intend uses of Google Fit to create obligations under the Health Insurance Portability and Accountability Act, as amended (“HIPAA”)" [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/terms#use_limitations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HIPAA compliance is a bit tricky because it relies on the ambiguous 'industry standard.'

In this particular case, I believe that you need an https:// sign-in service.  HIPAA compliance is typically satisfied by judicious use of cryptography and other standard security measures.